# In a WebView, how do I know if an event is being consumed by JS, is there any callback method or anything eles?

Tags: android

There is a "pull refresh" in `HTML`, and my `WebView`'s parent is `SwipRefreshLayout`.

When I pull down, I want `JS` to consume the event first but not `SwipRefreshLayout`. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just implement `ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener` in your Activity then set listener like `webview.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(this);`

and in `onScrollChanged()` method add if statement on `webview` vertical position value

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    if (webview.getScrollY() == 0) {
        swipeLayout.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        swipeLayout.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

this will check if `webview` is on the top and then it will enable `SwipeRefreshLayout` otherwise `SwipeRefreshLayout` will be disabled

Comment: but there is a "pull refresh" element in HTML,when webview is on the top, I want that "pull refresh" element to consume the event not the SwipeRefreshLayout

Comment: so what is the purpose of swipetorefresh layout ?

Comment: swiprefreshlayout refresh whole html, "pull refresh" element just refresh part...I know that is strange, but I must obey orders...

Comment: what do you mean by element ? could give please a real example ?